# Exception not caught in java program

Tags: java, exception, runtime

Im running an eclipse based Java application and im unable to catch the exception. Im trying to read an excel file and get its contents.Below is the sample code The program is able to identify the excel file and the execution stops when the program tries to create a new `xssfworkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);` object.

```
FileInputStream file = null;
    XSSFWorkbook xssfworkbook = null;
    try
    {
        //TODO Read file from Actual Path
        file = new FileInputStream("D:\\Import_Model_1.xlsx"); 
        xssfworkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        // TODO Handle the IO Exception with Logs, and User Friendly Message to User
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch( Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace() ;
    }
```

The execution of the program halts abruptly without specifying the cause. I have all the required  jars available in the class path. But unable to catch the exception. Any help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: can you put the stacktrace?

Comment: Maybe it is not stopped by an instance of Exception? Have you tried to catch Throwable?

Comment: Are you sure your application halts unexpectedly? Is there a chance that it just runs to the end and prints nothing?

Comment: One possible reason is that the XLS file is in use/open by any other application. Close it and it should be working.

Comment: Hi All, thanks for the immediate response. I tried to catch the throwable and got the below exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook. But the Poi jar is still available in the classpath. Im not sure why it is not recognizing the jar file.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting classpath properly using maven or something else. I guess the problem is not Exception

Comment: How come it is a `classpath` issue? If so, IDE might have made a complaint on that.